# Is there a way to find which firewall-profile is active?

Tags: python, powershell, firewall

I had a problem with servers connecting to the wrong firewall-profile so I am trying to find a solution to track this information.

I have already got the powershell commands in my python script:

```
subprocess.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles')
subprocess.check_output('netsh advfirewall show currentprofile')
```

I can also convert them to strings.
The actual problem is that these informations look very fractured and are probably not always in the same order on different systems, as well as different languages.

Is there a simple way to find which firewall-profile is on and active?
In the best case the function gives me a String like "yes"/"no" or a boolean.

Comment: `Get-NetFirewallSetting |% ActiveProfile` should tell you which one is active. For better parsable output, use `Get-NetFirewallProfile |ConvertTo-Json` then call `json.loads` on the python side to get structured data.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I only get "NotApplicable" as an answer. What does that mean?

Comment: I believe that means that your firewall is managed by Intune

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You just had not defined the PolicyStore to query - Details below...

Just use the following query - It returns the **names of all active policies** - For example "*Domain*"

```
Get-NetFirewallSetting -PolicyStore ActiveStore |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ActiveProfile
```

Additionally, there is to mention that "ActiveProfile" might contain multiple profiles, as a system can have more adapters that might need different settings. So this example might also be normal "Domain, Public"

Information about "PolicyStore" and why you need it pretty often:

> This store contains the currently active policy, which is the sum of all policy stores that apply to the computer

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallprofile

If you need **true** or **false** responses for each you could use this

```
$intvalue = (Get-NetFirewallSetting -PolicyStore activestore).`
CimInstanceProperties.Where{$_.Name -eq "Profile"}.value

$DomainEnabled = [bool]($intvalue -band 0x1)
$PrivateEnabled = [bool]($intvalue -band 0x2)
$PublicEnabled = [bool]($intvalue -band 0x4)
```

For this example you also can have multiple **$true** values